# Calling stored procedure which does not return a list using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I understand if my stored procedure returns a data set I can do this

```
    _context.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query, parameters).ToList<Product>()
```

But, If I have a stored procedure which does not return anything, how can I call that from entity framework? What goes in place of the "?" below?

```
    _context.Database.SqlQuery<?>(query, parameters).ToList<?>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you mapped the stored procedure to a function in the model browser yet?
If you go to your edmx file and right click, you can add->function import and then specify the details of the stored procedure you want to import.
This will map it to a function, you can then efffectively call your stored procedure using

```
_context.(NameYouGaveFunction)
```

Comment: I am doing "Code first with existing database", so I do not have an EDMX file